# Entity Framework: have two many-to-many relationships in one object where the other object is the same for both

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-framework-core

Here's the key parts of both classes:

```
public class User
{
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public required ICollection<Skill> SelfIdentifiedSkills { get; set; }

    public required ICollection<Skill> CertifiedSkills { get; set; }
}

public class Skill
{
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public required ICollection<User> CertifiedUsers { get; set; }
    public required ICollection<User> SelfIdentifiedUsers { get; set; }
}
```

When I run `Add-Migration` I get:

> Unable to determine the relationship represented by navigation 'Skill.CertifiedUsers' of type 'ICollection'. Either manually configure the relationship, or ignore this property using the '[NotMapped]' attribute or by using 'EntityTypeBuilder.Ignore' in 'OnModelCreating'.

I know this is a little weird having two collections of the same type in User. But not that unusual. Anyway, how can I get this to work? Preferably with a command in fluent (as opposed to attributes).

Comment: David - the technology you're using is **Entity Framework** - two separate words with a space between them, and **without** an "s" at the end of "framework" - so it's definitely **NOT** "EntityFrameworks", as you keep misspelling .....

Comment: @marc_s Sorry & thank you. (FWIW - I spelled Eurovision EuroVision for months before someone corrected me on that too.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can solve that by registering an entity configuration for either entity, in which you declare which property from that entity is related in what way to the property of the other entity.

In this instance, since User is probably a bit more dependant on Skills than vice versa, we'll make a `UserConfiguration`:

```cs
using Domain.Entities;

using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Metadata.Builders;

namespace Infrastructure.Data.PostgreSql.Configurations
{
    public class UserConfiguration : IEntityTypeConfiguration<User>
    {
        public void Configure(EntityTypeBuilder<User> user)
        {
            user.HasMany(user => user.SelfIdentifiedSkills)
                .WithMany(skill => skill.SelfIdentifiedUsers);

            user.HasMany(user => user.CertifiedSkills)
                .WithMany(skill => skill.CertifiedUsers);
        }
    }
}
```

Then in your `Context` class you apply the configuration during `OnModelCreating`. You can do that either explicitly for that configuration, or tell the context to find all configuration classes in a given assembly.

```cs
using Domain.Entities;

using Infrastructure.Data.PostgreSql.Configurations;

using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;

namespace Infrastructure.Data.PostgreSql
{
    public class DataContext : DbContext
    {
        // Properties
        public DbSet<User> Users => Set<User>();
        public DbSet<Skill> Skills => Set<Skill>();

        // Constructors
        public DataContext(DbContextOptions<DataContext> options) : base(options) { }

        // Methods
        protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder model)
        {
            // Either
            model.ApplyConfiguration(new UserConfiguration());
            // Or
            model.ApplyConfigurationsFromAssembly(typeof(DataContext).Assembly);
        }
    }
}
```